# IF statement to combine 7 columns

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have 7 columns that have a yes or no in them (N2-T2). I need an equation that will place a 1 in "AI2" if there is a yes in any of the N-T cells. In my previous work with Excel I have only used the colon in an equation if I am adding the cells. Is this correct or does it have more use?

I tried the equation below and I get an error; #Value!

=IF(N2:T2="yes",0,1)

I also tried this one, however Excel just kept telling me that it wrong. I just tried the first two columns in this example to see if I could make it work.

=IF(N2="yes",IF(O2="yes"),0,1)

Comment: The others have already answered your question with better ways to do it, so I just wanted to point out that the problem with your last attempt there is that the bracketing is wrong, and the order of the params. You need if(test, if-true, if-false) so something like: =IF(N2="yes", 1, IF(O2="yes", 1, IF(P2="yes", 1, IF(Q2="yes", 1, 0)))) - that's just for four cols to show the point.

Comment: Thank you Vicky. At least I feel better now, knowing that I had the process going good, just a little backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you are looking for is

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH("yes",N2:T2,0)),0,1)
```

Comment: a bit hard to understand for average users, but **very elegant**

Comment: Sorry still new to the site. I believe I just marked it as correct. If not, please let me know and I will make sure I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the logical OR function

```
=IF(OR(A1="YES";B1="YES";C1="YES";D1="YES";E1="YES";F1="YES";G1="YES");1;0)
```

This way you are more flexible on what you want to test (4th column "yes" OR 5th column "foo", etc.)

Likewise there is an AND(logical; logical; ...) function as well. Try to avoid cascaded IF's - they are hard to read and debug.

Comment: Thank you. I am definitely the average user, trying to complete my elegant statements. I appreciate your help on this.